# Query where "Number" column value is empty or is greater than X

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to provide a database-type Android for my users, where I'd like to take the following precausion for future compatibility: make certain rows/elements only available "since version X" of the app.

All versions of the app will query for entries and provide their version code in the query.

Now, I can successfuly retrieve rows that are supported in the current version using:

```
query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("sinceVersion", getCurrentAppVersionCode(this));
```

However, this does not account for and retrieve rows that have empty value for "sinceVersion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with [compound query](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-compound)

```
ParseQuery<TestParse> queryLessEqual = ParseQuery.getQuery(TestParse.class);
queryLessEqual.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("sinceVersion", getCurrentAppVersionCode(this));
ParseQuery<TestParse> queryDoesNotExists = ParseQuery.getQuery(TestParse.class);
queryDoesNotExists.whereDoesNotExist("sinceVersion");
ParseQuery<TestParse> compoundQuery = ParseQuery.or(Arrays.asList(queryLessEqual, queryDoesNotExists));
List<TestParse> list = compoundQuery.find();
```

where `TestParse` is your class from Parse.com